# Newtonsoft Json Serialization Conditional Serialization Kicking in Unexpectedly

Tags: c#, json, serialization, json.net

I've run into an odd issue with Newtonsoft Json conditional serialization kicking in unexpectedly.  I've distilled it down to a simple example (we're using newtonsoft json 5.0.8):

```
public class TestClass
{
    public string Foo { get; set; }
    public bool FooSpecified { get; set; }
    public TestClass()
    { }
    public TestClass(string foo, bool spec)
    {
        Foo = foo;
        FooSpecified = spec;
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        TestClass test1 = new TestClass("foo", false);
        string serial1 = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(test1);
        Console.WriteLine("Test 1: {0}", serial1);

        TestClass test2 = new TestClass("bar", true);
        string serial2 = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(test2);
        Console.WriteLine("Test 2: {0}", serial2);
    }
}
```

The output of the above:

```
Test 1: {"FooSpecified":false}
Test 2: {"Foo":"bar","FooSpecified":true}
```

It appears that having a bool property named 'xSpecified' where 'x' matches the name of another property acts as conditional serialization.  I haven't found this documented anywhere in the Newtonsoft json conditional serialization docs (http://james.newtonking.com/json/help/index.html?topic=html/ConditionalProperties.htm) nor has any googling shown other hits for this behavior.

Does anyone know if this is expected behavior or have I hit some sort of bug?

Comment: This looks relevant: http://json.codeplex.com/workitem/19091

Comment: I don't think it is a bug See https://github.com/ayoung/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/master/Newtonsoft.Json/Serialization/JsonTypeReflector.cs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe this is a bug. Either you're not finding the right docs, or it's undocumented but I would not call it a bug. Just to double check the behavior I used the following code to produce similar results.

```
TestClass test1 = new TestClass("foo", false);
string serial1 = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(test1);
test1.FooSpecified = true;
string serial3 = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(test1);
Console.WriteLine("Test 1: {0}", serial1);
Console.WriteLine("Test 1: {0}", serial3);
```

After a little research I found this was likely added to achieve parity with `XmlSerializer` which uses this `propertyNameSpecified` pattern for the same ends. This is the last comment I found about it from JNK, however, he must have changed his mind because clearly, it's been implemented.

http://json.codeplex.com/workitem/19091

EDIT: Adding the source link from LB's comment which clearly shows it was intentionally implemented; https://github.com/ayoung/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/master/Newtonsoft.Json/Serialization/JsonTypeReflector.cs

Also, if you read the full comments on that codeplex link you'll find the full story. JNK said he wouldn't implement it but would add it if someone else did. The final comment is someone saying they've done it. I would assume JNK made good on his end.

Comment: Thanks Evan; not a bug then.  I did get a chuckle out of JNK's comment: "I think the name of the property is more likely to accidentally trip someone up than the ShouldSerialize naming pattern" which is exactly what happened when someone added a new member in our code base and broke serialization. :)